# How to merge Multiple geojson in to one geojson in one FeatureCollection

Tags: php, mysql, leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I have multiple geojson type: FeatureCollection stored in Mysql. I want to merge two or more geojson in to one FeatureCollection geojson and show in my map. I have already leaflet map ready which can easily showing in map.

I read about Mapbox ‘geojson-merge’ but I unable to understand how use api in to my js or PHP file.

https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-merge

I search it for example on web but unable to find any guide about how to use with my online code.

Answer (score 12):

You can use it as a command-line tool.

First, install it:

```
npm install -g geojson-merge
```

Then to merge two geojson files run:

```
geojson-merge one.geojson two.geojson > combined.geojson
```

Answer (score 1):

This tools online works like a charm for me:
https://findthatpostcode.uk/tools/merge-geojson

I merged 5 files into one FeatureCollection